# Log file not found, there were undefined citations

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I have a article called `v2.tex` and a bibfile called `research.bib`. Both are in the working directory. I use windows and have installed MiKTeX and TeXstudio.

In the `v2.tex` file I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
some text from author \citet{clewlow} and \citet{pindyck}. 

\bibliographystyle{harward}
\bibliography{research}

\end{document}
```

And in the bibfile I have two articles, called "Clewlow" and "Pindyck".

When running bibtex and latex, I get

> there were undefined citations

in the tex file, and error that

> log file is not found

in the bibfile. The citations in the pdf ends up as question marks.

I have been googeling this for days, and I cant seem to figure it out! Any tips?

Comment: You cite the articles as "clewlow" and "pindyck" (small), and in the bib file they are called "Clewlow" and "Pindyck" (capital)?

Comment: Yes, this command is case sensitive.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I have a shared folder between a windows computer and mine which has ubuntu and once in a while these problems arise in Windows but not in ubuntu. I've compiled the file dozens of times without problems and just today the citations decided to be gone.

Comment: To be able to answer here, we'll need to see the `.bib` file and also the logs (or at least part of them). Until then, this is 'unclear' as we can't answer.

Comment: It's a TexStudio problem. TexStudio does not know where to look for the log file, which is in another directory as the current file being compiled. I tried to set a "master" file, which I expected would resolve the issue. Still looking for answer.

Comment: And here is a solution (or workaround as it is not entirely general): https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/614/